# Error Code: 1210. Incorrect arguments to MATCH on a View in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

So I have created a View in MySQL Workbench that pulls data from many different tables with the express purpose of using it as a base against which to run all of my full database searches; and all is fine and dandy till I try to include fields whose original type is not a string, cause I then get the message:

> Error Code: 1271. Illegal mix of collations for operation 'match'

So I think... not a problem, I´ll just cast this field to the proper collation like such:

```
select concepts_id,

MATCH(
  liabilities.id collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' AS "liabilities_id", 
  liabilities.label,
  liabilities.description,
  liabilities.comment,
  concepts.label,
    and many more fields...
)
AGAINST('my search string' IN BOOLEAN MODE) score
FROM view_made_up_of_several_tables
```

And sure enough I got rid of that message, but now I get a new one saying:

> Error Code: 1210. Incorrect arguments to MATCH

I did some research online and everytime the problem had to do with attempting a full search on many tables using a join and not constructing the appropiate fulltext_index first, but I don´t see this is my case since I´m only looking inside a single table, even though it´s a View constructed by many tables.
I've also tried:

> CONVERT(liabilities.id, CHAR) AS "liabilities_id"
> CAST(liabilities.id AS CHAR) AS "liabilities_id"

And I get the same Error Code:1210.
If I just comment out the non text fields, such as dates and numbers, everything works fine. I´ve ran out of ideas so any help would be much appreciated. Txs!